# Reconciling AICs and coefficient p values in Cox model

Tags: p-value, cox-model, aic

I’m building a Cox proportional model using two explanatory variables, A and B. The AIC for the model with only A is lower than the model with only B. This would lead me to believe that the model with A better fits the data. Of note, in each model, the p value for the coefficients of A and B were significant.

I then tried a model with both A and B in together. Surprisingly, only B was significant. This suggests that there is some degree of collinearity between the two variables.

Given the AIC info, I would have expected A to emerge dominant. Clearly that is an inappropriate simplification, but I would really appreciate a explanation of how this could occur. Thank you!

Comment: Check out [these threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=15.7+aic).